# Why is P(maximum of 3 functions >=3 ) = 1- prob. their intersection <= 3

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, actuarial-science

I have this question:

In a small metropolitan area, annual losses due to storm, fire, and theft are independently distributed random variables. The pdf's are:

Storm $e^{-x}$
Fire $\frac{2e^{-2x/3}}{3}$ 
Theft $\frac{5e^{-5x/12}}{12}$

Determine the probability that the maximum of these losses exceeds 3.

I read the solution and they have this step: 
$P[max\lbrace{S,F,T\rbrace} \leq 3] = P[(S\leq 3) \cap (F\leq 3) \cap (T\leq 3)]$.

So I understand that they've reworded it with the complementary probability. 
I just wanted to confirm that we can only make this statement of equality since we are using the complement. Else, we would need to find all the intervals where the maximum is greater than or equal to 3 and sum those.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your title you have $\geq$.  In your body you have $\leq$.  The statement with $\geq$ is false.  The statement with $\leq$ is true.  Clarify which you want to be asking about.

Comment: If $\max(S,F,T)\leq 3$, that implies that $S\leq 3$, $F\leq 3$ and $T\leq 3$.  Why?  Suppose otherwise.  Suppose without loss of generality that $S>3$.  Then $\max(S,F,T)\geq S>3$ and so $\max(S,F,T)\not\leq 3$ like originally hoped, a contradiction.

Comment: thank you! i edited my question.

Comment: and okay, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start: Give reasons for each equal sign and compute the answer.

Let $W = \max(S,F,T).$ Then
$$P(W \le w) = P(S \le w,\, F \le w,\, T\le w)\\
=P(S \le w)P(F \le w)P(T \le w) \\
= (1-e^{-w})(1 - e^{-(2/3)w})(1 - e^{-(5/12)w}).$$

*Note:* Based on the following simulation in R, you will find $P(W \le 5) \approx 0.84.$

```
m = 10^6;  s = rexp(m);  f = rexp(m, 2/3);  t = rexp(m, 5/12)
w = pmax(s,f,t);  mean(w)
## 3.148749
mean(w <= 5)
## 0.838767    # aprx P(W < 5)
pexp(5,1)*pexp(5,2/3)*pexp(5,5/12)
## 0.8385649   # exact P(W < 5)
```

[image]

I realize this is not exactly the numerical question asked, but it is
similar. I didn't want to do your assignment, but did want to show you
how to check your answer when you get it.